# Git push to specific branch with username and password

Tags: git, github, git-push

I need to push my changes to specific branch with username and password. So I found the following command to push directly with username and password.

```
$ cd demo   //branch name
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Test commit"
$ git push --repo https://username:password@bitbucket.org/name/repo.git
```

Here I need to push my changes to `demo` of the above url with username and password directly so that It will not ask me again. But as per the above command I found its not pushing to any particular branch. I need to commit my changes to that particular branch `demo` which also present in remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd demo` is not supposed to be a "branch name", just the name of the folder you have clone your repository.

- [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) would give you the name of the currently checked out branch.
- [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) would allow you to change branches.
- [`git branch -avv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) would show you all local and remote tracking branches

A simple [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) would push by default the current branch (for instance 'main') to `origin/main`, assuming it is already configured that way (a git clone would typically associate main to `origin/main`)

If origin is not set, you can add it with:

```
git remote add origin  https://username:password@bitbucket.org/name/repo.git
```

Although it is best to cache those credentials, using the helper configured locally: check the output of `git config credential.helper`.

Once you are on the right branch `my_branch`, the command would be:

```
git push -u origin my_branch
```